# Exception before the program starts c#

Tags: c#, exception

I have a project that runs fine, everything loads, runs and completes, this is only when i set visual studio in Debug mode, when i switch to Release, all hell breaks loose. 
The program does not even enter the main method, becouse when i put a console.Readline in there, the program still crashes. also i have put my whole program in a try catch block but becouse it doesnt even enter the main it will not catch anything. i have tried to seach for it on the internet but could find nothing usefull. What is going on here?

This pops up right after i press F5:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb3Xu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/msCCI.png

The exception window you see is somthing that is thrown inside my program, but is does not even get there?

Comment: Verify if you have somenthing on the build events. Right click the project > Properties > Build Events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the soltuion and select properties.

Click on Configuration Properties and then Configuration manager

In the Release section, make sure your projects are set to build (ticked) (sorry about the ugly picture)

[image]

Comment: This did the trick, one project was not ticked. Thank you very much! i will accept as awnser as soon as it alows me:)